# Attempt to build Qt from sources leads to error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I tried building more Qt versions (5.20., and 5.3.0 alpha) from sources, and I followed the instructions from [their website](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-building.html). I open up the Visual Studio 2013 x64 Native Tools command line.

My command line looks like this:

```
configure -debug -nomake examples -opensource -platform win32-msvc2013
```

The `configure` process runs apparently well. (I mean that don't get any error). Though, when I start building it, with this line:

```
jom
```

It works for about 5 to 10 minutes, then my command line reports the following errors:

```
c:\qt\qt5.3.0\qt-source\qtdeclarative\src\3rdparty\masm\assembler\MacroAssemblerX86Common.h(913) : see eference to class template instantiation 'JSC::AbstractMacroAssembler<JSC::X86Assembler>::JumpList' being compiled
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\QT-SOURCE\qtdeclarative\src\qml\Makefile.Debug [RegExpJitTables.h] Error 1
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\QT-SOURCE\qtdeclarative\src\qml\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\QT-SOURCE\qtdeclarative\src\Makefile [sub-qml-make_first-ordered] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\QT-SOURCE\qtdeclarative\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\QT-SOURCE\Makefile [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2
```

Where am I wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the error. And a log file would be much more useful than the console shot. Also I think this is a case where it would be more sensible to ask on the Qt mailing list or somesuch

Comment: where could I find the Qt log?

Comment: I mean the output of the make. Your shell probably has some kind of output redirection

Comment: Please, explain me where I can find that :)) I am not an expert in building things without my dear Visual Studio!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)

Comment: But as I said, this is off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: One way to get of the build log is to go to the console window *Properties->Layout* (from upper left corner menu), then change the screen buffer size to max 9999 lines. Then run `jom`, and after it fails, *Edit->Select all*, *Edit->Copy*. Paste to editor, save as original, then find the actual (first) error message and add to the question.

Comment: I am not really sure that it is off-topic since it is about a programming platform and about building a C++ source code

Comment: @Victor It is about a problem with building a library, not about a specific programming problem... I would suggest you to use the Qt support resources

Comment: Another thing, try [building from git](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) (also check the requirements there and see if you missed something with your first attempt).

Comment: @NiklasB. I believe questions about programming tools, including building them, is on topic at SO. Still this is perhaps not the best place to ask.

Comment: @Victor, the first (most important) part of error messages is missing in your screenshot. Please find the first `error:` string and copy that part to your question.

Comment: You are sure you are compiling qt? does not sound like qt errors

Comment: don't you see what source file it compiles? @qehgt, thre is no other error in the console, besides an error 1.  see my edit

Comment: Please remove the screenshot. It is useless ad it does not show the entire error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a quite similar problem some time ago.

If you want to build Qt5, then use the source from [GIT](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) cloning it:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
cd qt5
git checkout stable
```

Also, if you are not going to use webkit or any other lib, then just let it out - e.g.:

```
configure -debug-and-release -no-webkit -opensource -platform win32-msvc2013
```

It can take a while to finish processing. Go make a coffee and then come back later. Now if no error appears, run the [command](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/):

```
..jom.exe -j 8
```

It should work. Otherwise, just post a comment how it goes and we can follow up to ge it up and running.

Comment: how can we start a chat room? it looks promising but I have some more questions about gitting...

Comment: @Victor - Here some ways to talk: 1. Xchat > freenode > #qt :: avanz; or... 2. chat.stackoverflow.com > Android People (is an open forum); 3. add my facebook which is also on my mobile with live chat; 4. add my linkedin that gives a ring tone to my mobile if someone writes/add me; -- NB: keep in mind the time zone for Melbourne Australia www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=152

Comment: Alternatively you can also post a new question specifically about GIT and provide the link as a comment to the current post, and I can check what is the new question regarding GIT so it would be easy to follow up and address the sought answer for GIT.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved that by installing python 2.7.10 win32 and adding it to the system path. I guess there may be some py scripts that caused this problem.

Comment: I've add Perl, Python, Ruby executive files to the PATH variable (in Windows) and seems it helps to skip the error.